# How do I auto-update servlets without restarting tomcat in intellij?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, servlets

How do I auto-update servlets without restarting tomcat in intellij?

In Eclipse, if the servlet code changes without any special setting, it is automatically reflected.

However, in IntelliJ, even if the servlet code is changed, the changed code is reflected only by restarting the server.

It is the same even if you apply the settings through Googling. The changed code cannot be reflected without restarting the server.

How can I apply the servlet without restarting the server?

https://imgur.com/a/dkEDALV.png  I can't upload image because of reputation

Comment: You can use JRebel for this, but it does not come for free sadly.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the *Server* tab, change *On ‘Update’ action* to *Update classes and resources*.
2. Make sure your project war's *exploded* version is listed under *Deploy at server startup* in the *Deployment* tab.
3. Now run the web application in *debug* mode.